# Does .mov files keep the layers made in Adobe After Effects?

Tags: quicktime, layers, adobe-after-effects

I have a video in .mov format. Is there any way, after I import it to After Effects, to see the effects which are used and change the content ?

Answer (score 1):

No the .mov is already converted video file. It is like photo of the room(scene), you can see everything but you can't touch any objects on it, because it's photo.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can include a link to the After Effects project file in an output QuickTime movie, though.